# Which is the best way to archive data from one Informix 10 database to another?

Tags: sql, informix

I have **base** and **archive** dbs.  I have to copy records from **base** to **archive** and delete them from **base** for selected period of time. Application user can choose the period.

I think about writing a stored procedure. But it would be great if it can be done by some database configuration. 
I read about data replication but I am not sure it is appropriate. 
Is there a way to do it by configuration?

Comment: You should be planning to move off your Informix 10 DBMS to a newer version.  It has not been supported at all for a number of years now.  There've been versions 11.10, 11.50, 11.70 and 12.10 since 10.00 was released, and 11.10 and 11.50 are out of support too.

Answer (score 1):

zKalev.
Informix 10 is a pretty old engine (consider upgrading urgently), you are out of support.
If you mean Enterprise Replication, you can use it, supposing base and archive are in different database instances. It can even be on the same machine, but they need to be in different instances.

Comment: 10x for  response! I know that it is old,  but unfortunately it is not easy  to move to upper version . I wrote a stored procedure. It archive 15 000 records for 2 hours.  This is satisfactory for that moment . I am going to improve it later.